# From a 1-dimensional to a d-dimensional one.

Tags: integration, calculus

It is known that: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2+bx+c}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}+c}$$
This is obviously a 1-dimensional integral. I want to calculate the $d$-dimensional integral equivallent to this one, i.e.
$$\int e^{-aq^2+b\cdot q+c}d^dq$$
where now $q$ is a $d$-vector. I thought about decomposing the integral into d 1-dimensional integrals of the previous form, where I should devide the constant $c$ into $d$ equal pieces $c=\frac{c}{d}d$. The constant $a$ and the constant $d$-vector $b$ don't require something like that.

If I do this I get the following:
$$\int e^{-aq^2+b\cdot q+c}d^dq=\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)^{d/2}\left\{\exp\left[\frac{b^2}{4a}+\frac{c}{d}\right]\right\}^d$$

I was just wondering if I am doing it right. I'd really appreciate any answer.

Comment: Yup, that's right. 
You don't even need to worry about dividing the c, as you can extract it from the whole integral, and just multiply it back in at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the integral in the following form:
$$e^c \prod\int e^{-aq_i^2+b_iq_i}dq_i$$
Now you can use your formula for the 1-d integral.